# Update Multiple Rows Using An Inequality

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to update one column in a subset of a table but I can't figure out how to do it in a clean and efficient manner.

Consider the following:

```
// MyTable
id    name  flag
0     Steve 0
1     Bob   0
...
10500 Rick  0
```

I want to change `flag` to 1 but only for some of the cases. I tried to use

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET flag = 1
WHERE id <= 500
```

But obviously that does not work because the subquery returns more than one value. Technically, I could do it like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET flag = 1 WHERE id = 0
UPDATE MyTable SET flag = 1 WHERE id = 1
...
UPDATE MyTable SET flag = 1 WHERE id = 500
```

But who wants to do it like that? :) Is there a better way for me to format this query and only update those which match an inequality?

**EDIT**

To clarify exactly what's going on: when I say 'some of these cases' I only mean those which match the inequality, in this case `id <= 500`

When I run `UPDATE MyTable SET flag = 1 WHERE id <= 500` I get the following error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. 
This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=
    or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Comment: What are "some of these cases"?

Comment: Huh? what subquery are you talking about? `UPDATE MyTable SET flag = 1 WHERE id <= 500` should work. When you say it does not work, what do you mean?

Comment: As @MikeNakis asks, when you tried `UPDATE MyTable SET flag = 1 WHERE id <= 500` what *exactly* did not work?  (Did you actually try it?)

Comment: Please see my edit. I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: @Neurotrace: I agree with Mike, this should work... there is no subquery.  Is there anything else in the query window that may be executing after your 3 lines?

Comment: @RayK Nothing at all. The only query running is the one I've listed (with table/column name changes, of course). Specifically the query is `UPDATE Frame SET Reviewed = 1 WHERE FrameID <= 31437`

Comment: @Neurotrace - HLGem brings up a good point.  Is there a trigger or constraint set up on the table?

Comment: @RayK Hmm... It seems there is a trigger setup that could be causing the issue. I'll try to address this part myself then come back if I can't figure it out :) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SInce your query does not have a subquery, I would suspect that you have a poorly wrtten trigger on the table that expects only one record at a time to be updated. This needs to be fixed as no trigger should ever be written on this assumption. Triggers in SQL Server need to perform only set-based operations as they work against the whole set not one row at a time.

Comment: There does appear to be a trigger setup that I hadn't considered (oh the joys of updating ancient databases lol) Thanks for pointing that out, I'll see what I can do from here.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the primary use cases for conditional queries (use of a where clause).  You look for a way to uniquely identify the rows rows you wish to change and construct a query based on the identifying information.  Your initial attempt applies this concept, however, your table as constructed is so general that composing an adequate query to select out only the relevant information is difficult if not impossible.  Perhaps try changing the table to make the data more specific preferably by partitioning the data.  For example is there some way of grouping the data so that some people can be identified as "students" or "professors" etc?  What actually is flag supposed to indicate?

Comment: The only way to identify the rows is if their ID is less than a given value. `Flag` is actually just a new column in the table and defaults to 0. Only those rows with an ID less than or equal to X should be changed to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The query you have should work, if it is only that query, it should return the number of rows effected.

The long hand you wrote does exactly what your first query does. What environment are you running it in?

Comment: I'm running the query directly from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. No other queries are running.

Comment: Try just writing that little query in a new query window and running it, see if that work, which it should.